# Docker dealing with processes that don't end?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that has services running on multiple ports.

When I try to start one of these processes mid-way through my Dockerfile it causes the build process to stall indefinitely.

```
RUN /opt/webhook/webhook-linux-amd64/webhook -hooks /opt/webhook/hooks.json -verbose
```

[image]

So the program is running as it should but it never moves on.

I've tried adding `&` to the end of the command to tell bash to run the next step in parallel but this causes the service to not be running in the final image. I also tried redirecting the output of the program to `/dev/null`.

How can I get around this?

Comment: You need to look at the Reference for a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).  You can only have one CMD statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconception here. The commands in the Dockerfile are executed to create a docker image *before* it is executed. One type of command in the Dockerfile is [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) which allows you to run an arbitrary shell command whose actions influence the image under creation in some sense.
Therefore, the build process waits until the command terminates.

It seems you want to start the service when the image is started. To do so use the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) command instead. It tells Docker what is supposed to be executed when the image is started.

Comment: You have my upvote but switching to `CMD` did not solve my issue so I will leave question open. I have updated my question.

Comment: There is only one `CMD`  "slot". If you put it multiple times (I guess) the last one wins. You might write a script starting both your services (with & to run the first in the background) and put the script as `CMD` of the image.

Comment: This might help you further: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/